# JavaScript previous and next buttons to cycle through an array of .js files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, widget

I am having difficulty writing some JavaScript that will cycle through an array of .js files.

I have some JavaScript widgets saved in .js files. 
I want to be able to click a "Next" or "Previous" button to cycle through an array of those .js files and have the widgets called and displayed on my HTML page. They can be displayed in an iFrame if that would be a better solution.

I will continue researching until a kind soul helps out. Thanks a bunch in advance!

I have tried:

```
<script>
function onWindowLoad(){
    document.getElementById('js_type').innerHTML = ****.settings.type;


var widget_arr = [1column.js,2column.js,1row.js,modal.js]; //etc..etc..
var currentWidget = 0;
theBtn.onRelease = function(){
currentWidget++;
if(currentWidget == widget_arr.length){
    currentWidget=0;
}
var selectedWidget = widget_arr[currentWidget];
//now you have a variable pointing to the next widget..
//what you do with it is up to you.. add the code you need..
}
```

and this

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!--
// Use the following variable to specify 
// the number of widgets
var NumberOfWidgets = 4

var widget = new Array(NumberOfWidgets)

// Use the following variables to specify the widget names:
widget[0] = "1column.js"
widget[1] = "2column.js"
widget[2] = "1row.js"
widget[3] = "modal.js"

var widgetNumber = 0

function NextWidget()
{
widgetNumber++
if (widgetNumber == NumberOfWidgets)
    widgetNumber = 0
document.widgets["VCRWidget"].src = widget[widgetNumber]
}  

function PreviousWidget()
{
widgetNumber--
if (widgetNumber < 0)
    widgetNumber = NumberOfWidgets - 1
document.widgets["VCRWidget"].src = widget[widgetNumber]

<IMG SRC="modal.js" NAME="VCRWidget">

}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Code for the previous and next buttons:

```
<A HREF="javascript:PreviousWidget()">
<IMG SRC="prev.png" BORDER=0></A>
<A HREF="javascript:NextWidget()">
<IMG SRC="next.png" BORDER=0></A>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "cycle through an array of .js files"? are you loading the contents of these files? just providing links to these files? doing something that highlights an ability of each of these files?

Comment: loading the contents of these files(they are widgets) onto an html page, within an iframe if necessary. Essentially I want to be able to navigate to the site, have the first widget in the array load on the page, then when i click a next button, it will load the next widget.js file onto the page, etc...

Comment: Please take some time to read through the [faq].

Comment: sorry zzzzBov, I forgot to add my code examples, I have added them now

Answer (score 0):

One idea can be to use the fact thst even a static page can have parameters in the url. You can for example:

1. create the html page that will be opened in the `<iframe>` with any js include you need (e.g. jquery)
2. add to this page a js function that given a widget js filename will create a `<script>` tag loading the widget creation code.
3. extract the name of the js file to use to call the function in (2) from `document.location.href` by looking at the part of the string after `?`
4. in your main page create dinamically the iframe using for example `contdiv.innerHTML = "<iframe src=\"widgetpage.html?" + widgetname + ".js\"></iframe>";`

With this approach the widgets will be shown in a separate html page without interferring with your main page.